# How do I show the local available space instead of iCloud available space for synced folders?

Tags: icloud, finder

I generally keep all of my work files in a Projects folder in iCloud. It's become an effective replacement for Dropbox, allowing me to access project files on all my devices.

But the Finder's status bar at the bottom reports the available space on iCloud instead of locally.

[image]

I understand why it does this, but my iCloud space is much larger than the local storage, and I'm much more concerned with local storage, which I see in my home folder.

[image]

Is there a way to set it up so that even when looking at the synced folder, or any folder within it, the status bar reports the local storage available?